# Tensorflow Android camera demo, getting results in textview

Tags: android, tensorflow

Can anyone help, I want to get the Tensorflow results in TextView. I want to do something like

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text = recog.getTile();
```

I have tried myself but wasn't able to do that.

**Edit:**

By default scores are shown in canvas, instead of showing in canvas I want to get the results in textview.

[image: Tensorflow Android camera demo]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give more info.

Comment: @Distwo As shown in above picture, results are drawn on canvas, instead of showing in canvas I want to get the results or the only first one in string so I can use it.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan did you try this method text.setSingleLine(true); ??

Comment: @Javacoder Actually I am not able to get the data. Any thing I tried got exceptions.

Comment: share complete code...

Answer (score 3):

I've never used TensorFlow but from what I see [in this sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/287db3a9b0701021f302e7bb58af5cf89fdcd424/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java#L215):

You need to create an instance of `TensorFlowImageClassifier`

`classifier = new TensorFlowImageClassifier();`

Initialize it with your own parameters:

`classifier.initializeTensorFlow(...)`

Run the recognition which will give you back a list of some type of result objects.

`List<Results> classifier.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);`

In these results, you should have a title (ie. vending machine) and a confidence (ie. 0.973).

Once you have that you can just put it in your textview by doing `text.setText(result.getTitle);`